# Symfony 2.0 validator, Blank() doesn't work

Tags: validation, symfony

I am new on Symfony and I meet the following problem.
I'd like to generate a form without class. 
I want to add a Blank() validator on one field.
See below.

```
class searchPropertyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
            'keywords' => new blank()
        ));

        return array('validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint);
    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {       
        $builder
            ->add('keywords')
            ->add('neighborhood')
            ->add('price_min')
            ->add('price_max')
            ->add('type')
            ->add('date_from' , 'date')
            ->add('date_to' , 'date')
        ;


    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'searchProperty';
    }
}
```

The form is properly displayed but still, I can't send the form, I got a HTML5 alert saying that I must fill out this field.

ANy idea? I have been working on that the full day and it drives me crazy.

Thank you so much if you have time to help ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable HTML5 client side validation add `'required' => false` to `getDefaultOptions`:

```
    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
            'keywords' => new blank()
        ));

        return array(
            'validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint,
            'required' => false
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
        $builder

                ->add('neighborhood','text',array('required' => false,))
                ->add('price_min','text',array('required' => false,))
               ->add('date_from', 'date', array('widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'dd MMM yyyy', 'required' => false))
              );
    }
```

Add `required=>false`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I might be wrong but there is no need to repeat the `required` option as it's inherited when you specify it in `getDefaultOptions`.